# Can I boot Windows straight to my homepage instead of the desktop?

Tags: windows-7, browser, desktop

I pretty much put Windows 7 in hibernate at the end of the day.

What I would like know is can I change computer from going to desktop and instead go straight to my homepage.

Comment: What do you mean "straight to your homepage" you mean launch your browser.  Just write a script to launch your browser of choice.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a Scheduled Task that triggers upon awakening from a sleep or hibernate.

1. Click start
2. Type "sched" in search box
3. Choose "Schedule a Task"
4. Click "Create Task..." on the right
5. Give your task a name "home page"
6. Go to the triggers tab and click New...
7. Change the "Begin the task" dropdown to "On an event"
8. Change Log to "System", Source to "Power Troubleshooter" and Event ID to "1" - OK
9. Change to the Actions tab, New and Action is "Start a Program"
10. In Program/Script put "iexplore.exe"
11. In Add Arguments put the URL of the site you want to open when your machine comes out of hibernate.